# counting number of words between two strings python regexp

Tags: python, regex

I want to check if number of words between two strings in a larger string is < n. For example, suppose I have a string like "a quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog". I want to see if the distance between strings "brown fox" and "lazy dog" is < 5 in the larger string. What would be a proper python regexp for that?

I tried as per the [link](http://www.powergrep.com/manual/xmpnear.html). My code was

```
s='a quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog'
m=re.search("'brown fox'\W+(?:\w+\W+){1,4}'lazy dog'",s)
```

but there was no match.

Comment: Don't forget that characters like `'` are not part of the character class `\w`, and so something like `\S` (not-space) might be more appropriate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to match for single quotes, but there aren't any in the string:

```
>>> re.search("brown fox\W+(?:\w+\W+){1,4}lazy dog", s)
<_sre.SRE_Match at 0x3045850>

>>> re.search("brown fox\W+(?:\w+\W+){1,3}lazy dog", s)
<_sre.SRE_Match at 0x3045920>

>>> re.search("brown fox\W+(?:\w+\W+){1,2}lazy dog", s)
(None)
```

Comment: yes, that worked. can i accept more than one answers? both (yours and Patashu's) are correct. the error was matching for single quotes.

Comment: @rivu You can upvote both answers but you can only accept one, so accept the one you think is more helpful/indicative of more effort.

Answer (score 2):

Try `brown fox\s+(\S+\s+){0,4}lazy dog`